# Can't push to cloned repo

Tags: git, gitlab, gitkraken

Moving from Github to Gitlab. Cloned the repo, set up my keys, etc. I am using GitKraken (was using sourcetree before, but switched).

Issue: Push attempts to Gitlab fail with "git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey)" on one repo.

I created a new repo in GitKraken, set it to private and am able to push multiple commits via ssh without issue via GitKraken to Gitlab. this tells me there is no actual issue with keys or anything like that and that this error is a bit misleading. Settings are the same for both Repos, both are private, use SSH and have LFS enabled.

When I push to the repo I cloned from github, it throws up this error which is telling me there must be some kind of config issue or something, but I’m a bit of a novice at this and have no idea where to check to reset this kind of thing.

Edit: I ran  ssh -vT git@gitlab.com on both repos. Both finish with:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

However the repo that I created via gitkraken also returns that exact same output and I can push to it just fine.

For testing purposes, I generated an entirely new set of keys and now receive this on bash:

```
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_rsa':
Welcome to GitLab, @crossmr!
```

However, when I try to push with GitKraken now, GitKraken tells me: "configured SSH Key is in an invalid format".

Yet bash interface has no issue with it at all

Edit2: [Image of GUI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXDCl.png)

Here is the current GUI error, while pushing via bash gives me:

```
$ git push Gitlab master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/crossmr/.ssh/id_rsa':
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (18/18), 38 MB | 1.4 MB/s, done
Enumerating objects: 99, done.
Counting objects: 100% (99/99), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Writing objects: 100% (72/72), 7.07 KiB | 452.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 72 (delta 38), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitlab.com:crossmr/repo.git
4ccee92..d32d232  master -> master
```

Comment: is this repository yours? if not, you had to clone your own `fork`..

Comment: Yes, the repo is mine. I connected my github account to gitlab and cloned my own repo via their website interface.

Comment: have you registered your public keys to gitlab? seems you originally used keys for github and your git tried your keys to no avail..

Comment: Yes, they are registered. I added my bash output above for my new keys that I generated. Via bash they are working perfectly. In fact I am pushing via terminal right now, but the GUI claims there is a problem with my keys. When I tried to push it did ask me to put in my passphrase 3 different times. Maybe that is the problem? Should the passphrase be cached or something? I had to type it into bash and then I got an open_ssh pop-up twice to enter my passphrase 2 more times, then it started pushing